# Adjusting contrast in VIPS the same way as the matching CSS filter

Tags: ruby, image-processing, vips

I have a web app where users can use the filter contrast in order to modify an image : `filter: contrast(1.1)` that I would like to reproduce in VIPS. (In Ruby)

Though I have not found any information on how to do that in Vips yet. I saw Vips implement CLAHE algorithm https://github.com/libvips/libvips/issues/1576 but it is overkill for me and may not return the same kind of contrast adjustmeent similar to the CSS filter.

Also I checked this thread of adjustments examples yet I can't find anything for contrast adjustment : https://github.com/libvips/libvips/issues/59 ...

Also I ended up on W3 explanation page where they cleanly explain what is done for contrast adjustment : https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#contrastEquivalent

```
<filter id="contrast">
  <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncR type="linear" slope="[amount]" intercept="-(0.5 * [amount]) + 0.5"/>
      <feFuncG type="linear" slope="[amount]" intercept="-(0.5 * [amount]) + 0.5"/>
      <feFuncB type="linear" slope="[amount]" intercept="-(0.5 * [amount]) + 0.5"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

Definitely awesome.

Now I know they use a linear fonction (that I know how to leverage in Vips) and they stay in RGB colorspace. I have understood that a slope is just a multiplication being done. Which is easy to do as I just need to pass an array as the first argument of the Vips Linear function. http://libvips.github.io/ruby-vips/Vips/Image.html#linear-instance_method

Though I have basically no clue of what Intercept is and if Vips Linear function offers similar tool.

Any idea?

---

EDIT EDIT

Ok seems like W3 has been doing something funny.

The solution to exactly match CSS filter `contrast` with Vips is :

```
divider = 256
contrast = 1.5
intercept = 0.5-(contrast*0.5)
im = Vips::Image.new_from_file "pic.jpg", access: :sequential
im = ((im * contrast / divider) + intercept)*divider
im.write_to_file "output.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just multiply to change contrast. [From the CSS docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#feComponentTransferElement), `linear` just computes:

```
C' = C * slope + intercept
```

So in ruby-vips you could write:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'vips'

contrast = 1.1

image = Vips::Image.new_from_file ARGV[0], access: :sequential
image = image.colourspace("scrgb")
image = image * contrast - (0.5 * contrast - 0.5)
image = image.colourspace("srgb")
image.write_to_file ARGV[1]
```

[scRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ScRGB) is sRGB but with linear floats in the range 0 - 1 for black to white.

You could use `linear` rather than the operator overloads, it'd be slightly quicker.

```rb
image = image.linear contrast, -0.5 * contrast - 0.5
```

Comment: Hi John thanks a lot for your answer. Though I can't get it work on my end. Straight when converting my JPEG to "scrgb" I get a black image (without even performing any pixel change). If I stay in RGB then it just performs a brightness increase. (I guess the addition part is too tiny to make a difference and only the slope has an effect then). Still I am curious what the "intercept" is. I have been thinking it is the second argument (additional part) of the Linear function but I am wondering if it is not like a conditional thing ..

Comment: Oh dear, sorry, I've updated my answer. I should not post untested code heh! Yes, intercept is just the 0 offset.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't read the W3 specs in full .. Now I can indeed see a contrast improvement. It is a bit stronger than CSS for the same amount of contrast and saturation seems a bit stronger but I will investigate now I know what intercept is. I am wondering if it doesn't have something to do with a :sequential application of the linear function.I will read more about the different colourspace and play a bit with Vips. Thank you

Comment: I tried something: changing contrast in CSS to 1.5 and screenshotting my image then picking the color in GIMP. Then I pick the color and use a converter https://ajalt.github.io/colormath/converter/ to get the first channel in SRGB 0-1. Original image : 0.70588, dot in the same area on CSS screenshotted image : 0.80784, Vips image: 0.68627. With simple math,, from the original image I get 0.70588 * 1.5 - (1.5 * 0.5) + 0.5 = 0.80882 which is off from the VIPS image but quite consistent to the CSS screenshot. Although the scrgb colourspace seems pretty wide .. I don't get where the diff arise

Comment: Actually W3 might be using a Linear sRGB colorspace (this is really a guess) which involves the gamma https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/578#issuecomment-379467586 https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/578#issuecomment-379467586 I don't think Vips has such a colourspace but I will try to make the computation and see if I get something consistent. I get back to you in case I have some success

Comment: The vips conversion to scrgb makes linear 0-1, so it's using linear space. If you remove those colourspace conversions it's do the adjustment in plain sRGB gamma space and won't match.

Comment: Ok seems like I found what W3 did as per my edit. Sorry for having been a bit persistent  :)